# Obtener proceso que menos memoria consuma

Tags: powershell

estoy intentando obtener el pid del proceso que menos memoria consuma , en este caso , csrss

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

en este caso, hay dos procesos csrss, que cumplen diferentes funciones, yo quiero obtener el pid del proceso que menos memoria consume , en este caso, es el primero y siempre va a ser el que menos memoria consuma

(ninguno de los dos usa argumentos, asi que no es posible obtenerlo de esa manera)

Comment: ¿Pudieras compartir el script de PowerShell que estas usando?

Comment: aun no tengo nada